# How to determine USB hub speed type?

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, current, driver

I'm developing a driver for multiple USB speeds and according to the universal specification, I'm allowed to draw a greater amount of current from a USB 3.0 hub than the other versions.

Is there a way on Windows to determine the different USB speeds? I'm basically asking for a place to get started. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your question further. "The different USB speeds" of what? Do you want to determine the data-transfer speeds of the various USB ports on a given computer?

Comment: I want to clarify regarding USB normal/full/high/super speeds (mentioned in the specification)

Comment: For more info, you can check for normal/full speeds using the power settings of the USB hubs/devices

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using Windows, you should look into using `Windows Driver Frameworks` (WDF). This is the Windows equivalent to `libusb` on POSIX-compliant computers.

**[WDF Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463268.aspx)**

Look through the example code (there's a toaster/firefly driver example in there) on how to set up a `WDFIOTARGET` given a device ID. Use this implementation with your hub, enumerating it upon device insertion.

Then, you'll want to send the IOCTL, `IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_INFORMATION`, to the hub represented by a `WDFIOTARGET` in order to retrieve a `USB_NODE_INFORMATION` structure.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sgi.com](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/dynaweb_docs/0650/SGI_Developer/books/DevDriver_PG/sgi_html/figures/03-device.control.gif))</sub>

**[IOCTL Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

**[USB_NODE_INFORMATION Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540110%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

Then, retrieve with the following access pattern:

```
PUSB_NODE_INFORMATION UsbNodeInfo = NULL;
// retrieve UsbNodeInfo here with your USB_GET_NODE_INFORMATION signal
UCHAR DescriptorType;
DescriptorType = UsbNodeInfo->u.HubInformation.HubDescriptor.bDescriptorType
```

**[HubInformation Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540020%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

**[HubDescriptor Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff539331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

This will retrieve a descriptor type of either `0x2A` (3.0) or `0x29` (2.0 or lower). Using this information, you can send the proper `IOCTL` you want to the device in order to demand a greater amount of current from the hub like so:

```
if (DescriptorType == 0x2A) {
    // handle USB 3.0 current specification here
} else {
    // handle USB 2.0 current specification here
}
```

Hopefully this is enough for you to get started.

Comment: Minor correction - the windows equivalent to libusb is libusb - it's a an abstraction layer on any platform on which it runs, not the native way of doing things.